# SharpSvn Dump repository from tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn, dump, sharpsvn

we would like to do a dump from svnsharp we have seen the SvnRepositoryClient.DumpRepository method and we would like to know if there is a way to filter revision like parameters of svndumpfilter.exe.

Let me know

Regards,
Davide

Answer (score 1):

Subversion doesn't implement svndumpfilter as a reusable library yet, so there is currently no real way to use its specific features from the api.

I would recommend just calling svndumpfilter.exe from your application if you want to perform advanced filtering. (Don't forget to pass `--renumber-revs` if you drop revisions via other options. I lost quite a bit of time by forgetting that a few months ago)